# Multiple users, one public_html directory

Tags: linux, security, user-management, user-accounts, groups

New to creating users with linux. Trying to

1. add users in a secure manner, limiting damage a user can do
2. give all members of the webadmins group access to the public_html folder as projects are often shared
3. restrict the webadmins from any other directories besides the public_html folder (SFTP, etc)
4. use non-standard paths for my public_html location

I believe this is best done by

```
mkdir /nonstandard/path/public_html
```

Adding users by

```
useradd -d /nonstandard/path/public_html -g webadmins -m someuser -p password
```

Restricting them with [ChrootDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526919/linux-shell-to-restrict-sftp-users-to-their-home-directories)

**The Question**
Is this the correct, secure way?  Is it ok that users share a home directory?  How can this be improved?

Comment: imho, don't give them all same `home` dir but give everyone group privilege on the directory via `chmod 775`??

Comment: Thanks.  If they had access to the public_html directory, what would be gained by giving each user a different home directory?

Comment: A lot of programs use $HOME for storing state and configuration data. There are unintended consequences when users share $HOME. Linux/unix applications are designed with this philosophy in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Restrict SSH to admin users only. Allow normal users via FTP and chroot them in the home folder. vsftpd can do that. You can use SSL/TLS with FTP.
2. Assign permissions:

```shell
mkdir /nonstandard/path/public_html
chgrp -R webadmins /nonstandard/path/public_html
chmod -R g+r /nonstandard/path/public_html
find /nonstandard/path/public_html -type d -exec chmod g=rwxs \{\} \+
```

3. You can use [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) in apache. Configure also the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot)
4. See for this the apache configuration directive [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot).

Comment: THANKS!  1 - done.  2- thanks.  3 - haven't used su_exec.  If limited to 3 users, all partners, is there still a reason for su_exec.  Sorry, not familiar.  4 - was there supposed to be a link?

Comment: I've edited and added the links. I've changed the permissions to have set group ID for folders. In this way the users will be able to add files to that folder.

Comment: You do not need suEXEC if the users will collaborate and if they will edit the same site.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to protect. Take in consideration also to create a virtual machine for the site where the users have full or partial access. You can use Linux containers if you want only separation.

Comment: Great answer.  Answered a lot of questions.  Virtual machine is also an option.  Thanks!